# Start a PHP server from terminal for running PHP File on Rasperry Pi

Tags: php, server, raspberry-pi, ip, port

I have PHP and Apache2 installed on my Raspberry Pi, that works. But, I dunno how to run a server and connect to it from it's IP(http://192.168.1.25:22). And when I try another port, it says [Sat Mar  9 09:32:37 2024] Failed to listen on 192.168.1.25:80 (reason: Address already in use).

And : [Sat Mar  9 09:33:49 2024] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://192.168.1.25:22) started

I tried those techniques, like php -S 192.168.1.25:22 router.php but does not work, maybe port error ? I createda router, tried without router.

Comment: Here is a good guide for getting PHP and Apache setup on a Pi: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/2